# Create random curly line

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want (for demonstration purposes) a line beginning at one specific point (let's say `(0, 0)` with an exit angle of `90°`, going some loops (preferably randomly) and then returning at `(2, 0)` with an input angle of `90°`. Unfortunately I did not find any solution for that. What is the best approach for creating such a line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need is `random steps` decoration from `decorations.pathmorphing` library of `tikz`. Here is a sample.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [olive,thick, decorate, decoration={random steps,segment length=5pt,amplitude=3pt}]
 (0,0) to[out=90,in=90] (2,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Change the values in `segment length=5pt,amplitude=3pt` as you wish.

Here is a variation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [olive,thick, decorate, decoration={random steps,segment length=3pt,amplitude=1pt}]
 (0,0) -- (0,2mm) to[out=90,in=90,distance=3cm] (2,2mm) -- (2,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

They can be made to intersect each other.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [olive,thick, decorate, decoration={random steps,segment length=3pt,amplitude=1pt}]
 (0,0)circle (1.5);
 \draw [olive,thick, decorate, decoration={random steps,segment length=3pt,amplitude=1pt}]
        (2,0) to[out=40,in=135,distance=3cm] (3,0) to[out=225,in=40,distance=3cm] (2,-2);
   \draw [olive,thick, decorate, decoration={random steps,segment length=3pt,amplitude=1pt}]
        (4,0) to[out=40,in=135,distance=3cm] (5,0) to[out=40,in=135,distance=3cm] (6,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can I have this line intersecting with itself, i.e. making a loop?

Comment: @arc_lupus You mean a circle?

Comment: No, that the lines cross each other once or twice, forming loops.